# How to add package from sub-directory of monorepo with yarn

Tags: github, expo, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarnpkg-v2

I have a fork of the [expo](https://github.com/expo/expo) monorepo that has changes in only one of the sub-packages (e.g. expo-speech). I want to import only that sub-package in my application. Given these parameters:

- GitHub organization: `my-org`
- Repo: `expo`
- Branch: `main`
- Sub-package: `expo-speech`
- Sub-directory: `packages/expo-speech`

how would I add this package to my application using `yarn`?

Commands I have tried:

```
# with yarn 1.22.19
yarn add expo-speech@my-org/expo#workspace=expo-speech # fails with git error: "Could not read from remote repository."
yarn add expo-speech@my-org/expo#workspace=packages/expo-speech # fails with git error: "Could not read from remote repository."
yarn add expo-speech@my-org/expo#workspace=packages/@expo/expo-speech # fails with git error: "Could not read from remote repository."

# using https://gitpkg.vercel.app/
yarn add 'https://gitpkg.now.sh/my-org/expo/expo-speech?main' # fails with 500 or 504, no message

# with yarn 3.3.1
yarn add expo-speech@my-org/expo#workspace=expo-speech # never finishes
yarn add expo-speech@my-org/expo#workspace=packages/expo-speech # never finishes
yarn add expo-speech@my-org/expo#workspace=packages/@expo/expo-speech # never finishes
```

Most of the attempts above are from this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4725#issuecomment-753416391). I can find very little about importing from sub-directories or yarn workspaces of monorepos.

Comment: Same issue here, did you find a solution?

Comment: @AlexanderTelegin no. :( I ended up cloning the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following comment from github this should solve your issue with yarn v3:

`yarn add expo-speech@https://gitpkg.now.sh/api/pkg.tgz?url=my-org%2expo%2Fpackages%2Fexpo-speech&commit=main`

Original comment:
https://github.com/EqualMa/gitpkg/issues/22#issuecomment-834171060